# Concat list of string in a comma separated string on Oracle (hidden parameter)

Tags: sql, oracle

On an Oracle type database I have a list of strings in a parameter that I can't edit, I don't even have access to see the table structure.

All I know is that if I do somenthing like that:

```
select concat(?parameter) as results
```

I got

```
abcxyz012
```

So let's assume that this output depends on something like

```
select concat( "abc", "xyz", "012" )
```

Is there any way that I can get

```
abc,xyz,012
```

Or similar?

EDIT: Please note that the point here is that the parameter - the list of strings - is a variable whose value and length vary by user and is not known a priori.

The purpose of this query is precisely to identify all the strings that make up the parameter

Comment: "The purpose of this query is precisely to identify all the strings that make up the parameter" How do you determine if the strings should be `abc,xyz,012` or if it should be `abcx,yz01,2` or any other combination of lengths?

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, `CONCAT` only takes 2 arguments so you would need to use:

```sql
SELECT CONCAT( 
         'abc',
         CONCAT(
           ',',
           CONCAT(
             'xyz',
             CONCAT(
               ',',
               '012'
             )
           )
         )
       ) AS value
FROM   DUAL;
```

or, use the string concatenation operator `||`:

```sql
SELECT 'abc' || ',' || 'xyz' || ',' || '012' AS value FROM DUAL;
```

*(Note: In Oracle, double quotes `"` signify case-sensitive identifiers such as table/column names. If you want a string literal then you need to use single quotes.)*

Both of which output:

> ```
> | VALUE       |
> | :---------- |
> | abc,xyz,012 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c339243c166c3efb6450ed300e5740dd)*

---

If you want to split the string into 3-character substrings then:

```sql
SELECT SUBSTR(value,1,3) AS value1,
       SUBSTR(value,4,3) AS value2,
       SUBSTR(value,7,3) AS value3
FROM  (
  SELECT 'abc' || 'xyz' || '012' AS value FROM DUAL
);
```

Outputs 3 columns:

> ```
> VALUE1 | VALUE2 | VALUE3
> :----- | :----- | :-----
> abc    | xyz    | 012
> ```

Else, if you want one delimited value then, if the string is fixed length:

```sql
SELECT SUBSTR(value,1,3) || ',' || SUBSTR(value,4,3) || ',' || SUBSTR(value,7,3) AS delimited_value
FROM  (
  SELECT 'abcxyz012' AS value FROM DUAL
);
```

Or, if the string is variable length and does not end with a comma:

```sql
SELECT RTRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(value,'(...)', '\1,'),',') AS delimited_value
FROM  (
  SELECT 'abcxyz012' AS value FROM DUAL
)
```

Which both output:

> ```
> | DELIMITED_VALUE |
> | :-------------- |
> | abc,xyz,012     |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e94544c3e7b513c7df6e3545957a0356)*

Answer (score 0):

If You are receiving the `abcxyz012` and you want to convert it to `abc,xyz,012` then You can use `substr` as follows:

```
select substr(results,1,3) || ',' || substr(results,4,6) || ',' || substr(results,7,9)
  from (your_query)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I wasn't very clear in expressing my request, the answer to my question was simply:

```
select concat_ws(',', ?parameter)
```

Thanks for your solutions anyway!

Comment: `ORA-00904: "CONCAT_WS": invalid identifier` [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f80d34cc998e5a1af7ddb468b74ef21b)

Comment: Are you sure you are using an Oracle database and not another RDBMS such as MySQL?